# ListView element background - resource mutable()

Tags: java, android, listview, background, mutated

I have problem with my ListView. I want to set every second element in listView to have its background transparent. I use following code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row_object, null);

            Drawable backgroundDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abstract_gray);
            if((int)(position%2)==1)
                backgroundDrawable.mutate().setAlpha(ToolsAndConstants.BACKGROUND_TRANSPARENCY);

            // It is not working sometimes when I just use v.setBackground(backgroundDrawable); here. Why?
            v.setBackground(backgroundDrawable.mutate());

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rowNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row2_number);
            holder.character = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row2_char);
            holder.strokesNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_row2_strokes_number);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        (...)
        (...)
        (...)
        return v;
    }
```

The list loads fine, but the problem is that when I scroll it several times up and down it gets totally crazy (?Randomly? sets transparent background and solid background). Please refer to the screenshots below (before and after scrolling):

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Outside adapter class I just add onClickListener in which I replace fragment with different one. There is no onScrollListener etc. Why the layout is changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the view of list item is reused, you need to reset background each time when the getView method being invoked not only when convertView is null. e.g.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     ....
     if (v == null) {
         // Inflate the view without set the background
     }

     // Set the background based on position
     ...
}
```

Comment: But when I scroll the list, getView is not invoked...And before that layout is good. But your solution fixed the problem - I totally don't understand why. If the getView method is not invoked during scrolling, and before scrolling everything looks good, why your answer is a solution?

Comment: Also please tell me why I have to use mutate() twice.

Comment: @Marek getView will be invoked during the scroll when there's new list item to display. i don't know about the mutate, i would suggest to use two different drawable, one for the transparency and one for another.